# Launching a phone call from Broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, android-intent

I  am trying to launch a a phone call in the event of Broadcast.At the moment i am calling another activity from the onreceive() method of the Broadcast receiver.In that activity i am using this intent

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel"+num));
     callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     con.startActivity(callIntent);
```

The problem is that call gets disconnected immediately after launching.
i am trying this on galaxy nexus 4.1.1 and i used the following permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

i am a beginner to android any help would be welcomed.

when the call automatically ends this comes in the LogCat:

```
ActivityManager(387): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxxxxx flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.phone/.OutgoingCallBroadcaster} from pid 6329

 I/ActivityManager(387): START u0 {act=com.android.phone.SIP_SELECT_PHONE dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxxxxx flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.phone/.SipCallOptionHandler (has extras)} from pid 577

D/CallController(577): placeCall()...  intent = Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxxxxx (has extras) }

 I/AudioService(387):  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from AudioFocus_For_Phone_Ring_And_Calls

 E/audio_hw_primary(131): Entering IN_CALL state, in_call=0

 E/audio_hw_primary(131): Opening modem PCMs

 I/LocalDevicePlayback(6366): pause: transient=false, currentPos=-1

D/PhoneUtils(577): placeCall()... number: xxxxxxxxxxxxx, GW: null, emergency? false
```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

Comment: please post the logcat logs...

Comment: Did you happen to find the solution ? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code at my end and it was working fine at my end after one little change. I think the problem is that you need to put a `:` after the `tel`. Following is the corrected code..

```
String url = "tel:123456789";
            Intent dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
            dialIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(dialIntent);
```

Comment: I have added the Logcats to the question the problem persists.